# Embed vimeo player in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, embed

I want to allow users to submit a vimeo url and embed that in a player. Is there a plugin or gem that does that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo has details on how to embed using their API:
http://www.vimeo.com/api/docs/oembed

Under their "unofficial downloads" page, there is this gem:
http://github.com/matthooks/vimeo

Comment: Turns out I don't have to do anything except remove 'h' in front of it...obviously that leaves a big opening for hackers. I'm using 'sanitize option'...is that enough?

Comment: Remove h from in front of what?

Comment: <%=h app.description %> From what I understand 'h' prevents sql injections by hackers, and also embedding of stuff, unless you specifically allow for it with sanitize.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I found myself in the same situation.

If you wan't to retrieve Vimeo iframe for your video you can use the following code. No need to add a gem.

#### Add helper

Just create a file `app/helpers/videos_helper.rb` and the following lines.

```ruby
module VideosHelper

  require 'net/http'

  VIMEO_REGEX = %r(^https?:\/\/(?:.*?)\.?(vimeo)\.com\/(\d+).*$)

  # Finds Vimeo's video ID from given URL or [nil] if URL is invalid
  def find_vimeo_id url
    url     = sanitize url
    matches = VIMEO_REGEX.match url.to_str
    matches[2] if matches
  end

  # Get Vimeo video iframe from given URL
  def get_vimeo_iframe url, width, height
    vimeo_id = find_vimeo_id url
    uri      = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/#{ vimeo_id }&width=#{ width }&height=#{ height }"
    response = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( uri ))
    json     = JSON.parse response
    json['html'].html_safe
  end

end
```

#### Get iframe in view

In your view just call `get_vimeo_iframe()` to print the iframe.

```
<%= get_vimeo_iframe('http://your.vimeo.url') %>
```

Or if you want you can add width and height

```
<%= get_vimeo_iframe('http://your.vimeo.url', '800px', '450px') %>
```

If you want I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/a-barbieri/a93281cd5c01025664e5cbd781cd917c) which lets you ask also for **YouTube** iframe (not just Vimeo).