# Current Rails gem for Vimeo API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, vimeo, vimeo-api

I know that currently Vimeo supports API v.3.2 and Vimeo hasn't supported Ruby libraries ([list of supported libraries](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries)).

So what gems I can use to integrate upload video to Vimeo to Rails 5 application?

Comment: If you want to retrieve a Vimeo iframe you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44390475/1498118) which doesn't need any dependency.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a more recent [Vimeo API 3-compatible gem called VimeoMe2](https://github.com/bo-oz/vimeo_me2).

Comment: Just open your `Gemfile` and put `gem 'vimeo_me2', :git => "https://github.com/bo-oz/vimeo_me2.git"`, Read this's gem's documentation and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

As of writing this answer, I could not find any gem that support Vimeo API  V3. So for now your only option is to call API endpoints manually using HTTP calls (you can use HTTParty gem for it).